# External tables for files in the Infrequent Tier on the object store

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Can external tables be created in ADW from data in Object Storage "Infrequent Tier" or must it be "Standard Tier"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create external tables on the Standard and Infrequent tiers. Only the Archive tier is [not supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/file-uri-formats.html#GUID-A24852D3-9FB3-48DC-B0FD-3311DF9A57F1) at this time.

Here's an example showing an external table accessing a file in the Infrequent tier.

[image: File in the Infrequent tier]

```
SQL> drop table channels_ext;

Table dropped.

SQL> 
SQL> begin
  2   dbms_cloud.create_external_table(
  3      table_name =>'CHANNELS_EXT',
  4      credential_name =>'OBJ_STORE_CRED',
  5      file_uri_list =>'https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/n/adw/b/test/o/channels.csv',
  6      format => json_object('type' value 'CSV', 'skipheaders' value '1'),
  7      column_list => '
  8          channel_id          NUMBER(6)      NOT NULL,
  9          channel_desc        VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
 10          channel_class           VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
 11          channel_class_id        NUMBER(6)      NOT NULL,
 12          channel_total       VARCHAR2(13)    NOT NULL,
 13          channel_total_id        NUMBER(6)      NOT NULL'
 14   );
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> select count(*) from channels;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     5
```